# Mysql use of views across databases

Tags: mysql, view

I am using myISam tables ONLY for this, and have two accounts/databases named cpm155 and cpm179.

I have a group of tables in cpm155 which I have deleted (made a backup first), and then run the following queries for each one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cpm155.financial_items AS SELECT * FROM cpm179.financial_items;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cpm155.financial_headers AS SELECT * FROM   cpm179.financial_headers;
```

/* etc */

then I ran this query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON cpm179.* TO cpm155@localhost;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON cpm155.* TO cpm179@localhost;
```

so you would think that there would be no permissions problems.

I have two questions:
1. should update, insert and delete operations work normally in both databases since the view->table is a one-to-one correspondence?
2. are there any other gotchas that I am missing here?

Thank you! Sam

Comment: another thought is, those financial_ tables in cpm155 had views that referenced them.  It appears that these views continue to function normally even though the tables they reference are now views.  Any comments are appreciated!